# Can I get the view counts of a video by date using YouTube Data API v3?

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to find out the how “trending” a video is. Is there a way to get video counts by date?

Like this:

2020/5/11 1,234,567

2020/5/10 1,200,000
...

Or maybe new views increased by date? Or view counts at a certain date? I’m fine with everything.

## Updates

Last night was pretty late, and I did not realize I can get so many downvotes!

1. I am able to "connect" the YouTube Data API and OAuth 2.0 with my credentials. I am referring to the documentation of the former, which can be found here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs
2. From my reading, I had found (and tried) `rate` and `getRating` methods under "Videos" section. Obviously they did not work since `rate` can be used when "I" upvote a video and `getRating` can only get a binary result (whether "liked" or not).

[What I did with `getRating`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IH0Ku.png)

```
request = youtube.videos().getRating(
    id="Ks-_Mh1QhMc,c0KYU2j0TM4,eIho2S0ZahI"
)
response = request.execute()
response
```

3. Then I tried changing the `part` argument under list under "Videos". This gladly works. However, it only gets the views, likes, and dislikes right now.

[What I did with changing `part` argument](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKVX8.png)

```
request = youtube.videos().list(
    part="id, statistics",
    id="njn6krU3tQ8"
)
response = request.execute()
response
```

4. Now the problem is how can I get views, likes, and dislikes by date? From what I read from the documentation, there's nothing related to "date" under `list'. I also did some research about this. Of course, no answers can solve my question, at least from my research.

## Miscellaneous stuffs for my current comment(s) and answer(s)

1. I do not have any data. The point of these is to collect some data in order to use later in R, which I am more familiar with.
2. This is not my "work". I am doing a research on "how covid 19 affect YouTube views" sort of stuffs. I just want to find out if I can find anything interesting.
3. I am sorry that I did not add enough information about what I was currently doing. I was too tried and stayed late yesterday.

Comment: can you show some data that you have?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a place for you to find help with your problems, however this is not a place for people to do work for you. If you have a question, show how much of you've done, what were the problems you found, preferably with sample code. So, first; TRY something. Then SHARE it here. After that I'll be happy to remove the minus vote and add answer

Comment: @DallaRosa Thank you for your reply. I've edited my question with more details!

Comment: @AbhishekVerma Thank you for your reply! My point is to collect data, not manipulate it. Please see more details in my edits!

Answer (score 1):

Querying the [YouTube Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/channel_reports#video-reports) for video reports can return the metrics of a video for a specific period.

Just set the `dimensions` parameter to `video,day` if you want the results for each video per day and specify the video ids in the `filter` parameter.

The scope needed for this is `yt-analytics.readonly`.

Answer (score 0):

If the data you can get in a dataframe, then using groupby() function for Pandas Dataframe, you achieve your desired result.

```
df.set_index('your_column_name').groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D')).sum().dropna()
```